# PHP PDO can't bind a float parameter to search by integer field

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I have a question related to PDO and Postgres:

I'm getting an error when I'm trying to search with a `float` value by `integer` field:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT t.* FROM my_table t WHERE t.integer_field > ?');
$stmt->execute([9.5]);
```

This also doesn't work:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT t.* FROM my_table t WHERE t.integer_field > ?');
$stmt->execute(['9.5']);
```

This also doesn't work:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT t.* FROM my_table t WHERE t.integer_field > ?');
$param = 9.5;
$stmt->bindParam(1, $param, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

The error: `Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "9.5"`

Is this by design or it's postgres/pdo incompatibilities?

Btw it works when I inline the float without quotes:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT t.* FROM my_table t WHERE t.integer_field > 9.5');
$stmt->execute();
```

And postgres doesn't type-juggle to int because I see different records when I run these queries:

```
$con->prepare('SELECT t.* FROM my_table t WHERE t.integer_field < 5.1');
$con->prepare('SELECT t.* FROM my_table t WHERE t.integer_field < 4.9');
#given that integer_field is 5
```

Versions:
PHP 7.2.19
PostgreSQL 10.4

Comment: An integer cannot contain a decimal. All whole numbers are integers (and all natural numbers are integers), but not all integers are whole numbers.

Comment: True, but I can query "WHERE t.integer_field/2 > 9.5"

Comment: That probably has to do with the way you are passing the variable inside of `execute()`. I suspect if you wrap `9.5` in quotes/single quotes it would work, but I''m not totally sure on that since you would be checking if a string is `>`.

Comment: `execute` _All values are treated as PDO::PARAM_STR_.  Try using `bindParam` with `PDO::PARAM_INT`.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton AbraCadaver Thanks, I tried your suggestions, but they don't work either

Comment: IMHO it's clearer if you specifically make it an integer (by casting) - `$stmt->bindParam(1, (int)$param, \PDO::PARAM_INT);`

Comment: @NigelRen You can't pass parameter by reference :)

Comment: @NigelRen I agree in general but OP will need to watch out if they were to query `WHERE t.integer_field < ?` instead because the float would have allowed inclusion of `9` whereas your suggestion would exclude it.

Comment: OK - just set it beforehand - `$param = (int)9.5;`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - would be interesting to test what SQL would do with it - I'm not sure if it's converted prior to testing or it retains the decimals in the test.

Comment: It will truncate to int - what's the point if I want to pass the float inside the query?

Comment: @karser Are you saying that if you use `SELECT t.* FROM my_table t WHERE t.integer_field < 9.5` then PostgreSQL would type-juggle it into `SELECT t.* FROM my_table t WHERE t.integer_field < 9`?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus it doesn't type-juggle, see the updated question.

Comment: I would try setting `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` to `false` per https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php because I think your error is caused before the SQL has a chance to reach the DB and keep the `$stmt->bindParam(1, $param, \PDO::PARAM_INT);` code

Comment: @karser By using `t.integer_field*1.1 < 5.5` you have forced the left side to be a float just like the right. You need to leave `t.integer_field` alone and see whether `< 5` and `< 5.5` produce the same records.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I tried setting PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES to false (at least through doctrine options https://coderwall.com/p/goyc8w/how-to-stop-doctrine-from-turning-integer-into-string ) - same result

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Tried leaving the left side alone - neither works. I updated the question

Comment: I can't tell whether you are purposely not querying my exact examples or simply do not understand the difference between float and int. I am basically trying to have you test whether or not using `(int)$param` is safe.

Comment: I do understand the difference and I purposely don't do that because there is no problem with binding integer parameters in PDO. if I cast float to int it will be 9 but not 9.5.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus anyways big thanks for your efforts!

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I posted a working solution, wdyt?

Comment: @karser If it's working then that's good. Does it fail it you use `$stmt->execute([9]);`? I am just guessing based on the premise of your initial question.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Just tried - it works the same way. Float is converted to string, integer is untouched as I understand.

Answer (score 0):

After a while I figured out the working query:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT t.* FROM my_table t WHERE CAST(t.integer_field AS FLOAT) > ?');
$stmt->execute([9.5]);
```

Please, don't hesitate to post other answers if you have an alternative solution!

Comment: Is this with `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` switched to true or false?